# Creating a new data frame using dplyr and adding a column

Tags: r, dplyr

First of all, I am using the `ukpolice` package. We needed to select data from a specific city for 5 months, this dataframe is called `crimes`.

Now, we need to create a new dataframe that contains the columns: `category`, `month` and `number`.

The columns category and month already exist, but the column number still needs to be created. We are supposed to do this using the dplyr functions.

I created a frequency table using:

```
number_crime_type <- table(crimes$category)
```

In this table, the frequency per crime is established.

But I don't understand how I can create a new column in which the number of the crime is mentioned.

I'm really a rookie with R, so I really don't understand a lot of it.

How can I create a column that entails the number of the crime and add this column to the new dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Nikki,

If you don't already have it, install the `tidyverse` package by: `install.packages('tidyverse')` then load the package `library('tidyverse')`.  This will ensure that you have the `dplyr` package.

If the `count` is a column in the `crimes` dataset you can do this:

`new_dataframe <- crimes %>% select(category, count)`

If you need to calculate the count based on the frequency of a given category, do this:

`new_dataframe <- crimes %>% select(category) %>% group_by(category) %>% summarize('count' = n())`

Good luck!